# SQL Cross Apply Performance Issues

Tags: sql, distance, apply

My database has a directory of about 2,000 locations scattered throughout the United States with zipcode information (which I have tied to lon/lat coordinates).

I also have a table function which takes two parameters (ZipCode & Miles) to return a list of neighboring zip codes (excluding the same zip code searched)

For each location I am trying to get the neighboring location ids. So if location #4 has three nearby locations, the output should look like:

1. 4  5
2. 4  24
3. 4 137

That is, locations 5, 24, and 137 are within X miles of location 4.

I originally tried to use a cross apply with my function as follows:

```
SELECT A.SL_STORENUM,A.Sl_Zip,Q.SL_STORENUM FROM tbl_store_locations AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SL_StoreNum FROM tbl_store_locations WHERE SL_Zip in (select zipnum from udf_GetLongLatDist(A.Sl_Zip,7))) AS Q 
WHERE A.SL_StoreNum='04'
```

However that ran for over 20 minutes with no results so I canceled it. I did try hardcoding in the zipcode and it immediately returned a list

```
SELECT A.SL_STORENUM,A.Sl_Zip,Q.SL_STORENUM FROM tbl_store_locations AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SL_StoreNum FROM tbl_store_locations WHERE SL_Zip in (select zipnum from udf_GetLongLatDist('12345',7))) AS Q 
WHERE A.SL_StoreNum='04'
```

What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this listing of nearby locations? Keeping in mind while I used "04" as an example here, I want to run the analysis for 2,000 locations.

The "udf_GetLongLatDist" is a function which uses some math to calculate distance between two geographic coordinates and returns a list of zipcodes with a distance of > 0. Nothing fancy within it.

Comment: A side comment not directly related to your question, but we found that the centroid lat/long positions for zip codes were often quite distant from the place within the zip code where most people reside when it was a rural zipcode. So we used two positions, zipcode centroid lat/long, and lat/long of the primary town/city associated with the zipcode. A zipcode was considered near if either of those two locations was within x miles of the target location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers here involve re-working the algorithm.  I personally advise the pre-calculated map of all zipcodes against each other.  It should be possible to embed such optimisations in your existing udf, to minimise code-changes.

A refactoring of the query, however, could be as follows...

```
SELECT
  A.SL_STORENUM, A.Sl_Zip, C.SL_STORENUM
FROM
  tbl_store_locations                 AS A
CROSS APPLY
  dbo.udf_GetLongLatDist(A.Sl_Zip,7)  AS B
INNER JOIN
  tbl_store_locations                 AS C
    ON C.SL_Zip = B.zipnum
WHERE
  A.SL_StoreNum='04'
```

Also, the performance of the CROSS APPLY will benefit greatly if you can ensure that the udf is INLINE rather than MULTI-STATEMENT.  This allows the udf to be expanded inline (macro like) for a much cleaner execution plan.

Doing so would also allow you to return additional fields from the udf.  The optimiser can then include or exclude those fields from the plan depending on whether you actually use them.  Such an example would be to include the `SL_StoreNum` if it's easily accessible from the query in the udf, and so remove the need for the last join...

Comment: This worked so well! It ran all the locations in about 90 seconds. Can you explain why yours performed so much better than mine? I will also look how the udf is configured.

Comment: @user1181412 - The basic difference is that yours used `IN`, and mine used `JOIN`.  And that mine kept the function call in the same scope as your main table.  These, I suspect, meant the optimiser had a clearer view of the relationships and built a better plan.  Particularly, it possibly ran the udf once as a set if it's already InLine.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the function you probably have to calculate every single possible distance for each row. That is why it takes so long. SInce teh actual physical locations don;t generally move, what we always did was precalculate the distance from each zipcode to every other zip code (and update only once a month or so when we added new possible zipcodes).  Once the distances are precalculated, all you have to do is run a query like

```
select zip2 from zipprecalc where zip1 = '12345' and distance <=10
```

Comment: Thanks. That was actually my goal to create a pre-compiled list so I would only have to update this periodically. Someone below posted a query which runs much faster than mine.

Answer (score 1):

We have something similar and optimized it by only calculating the distance of other zipcodes whose latitude is within a bounded range. So if you want other zips within @miles, you use a

```
where latitude >= @targetLat - (@miles/69.2) and latitude <= @targetLat + (@miles/69.2)
```

Then you are only calculating the great circle distance of a much smaller subset of other zip code rows. We found this fast enough in our use to not require precalculating.

The same thing can't be done for longitude because of the variation between equator and pole of what distance a degree of longitude represents.